# There are infinitely many prime number $p$ such that $p≡3\pmod4$ and $p$ splits completely in $K$.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $K$ be a number field which does not contain $\Bbb{Q}(i)$.
Then, I want to prove there are infinitely many prime number $p$ such that $p≡3\pmod4$ and $p$ splits completely in $K$.

To prove this kind of theorem, Chebotarev's density theorem should work well.

What I know is following.

・In Galois extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ of degree $n$, $1/n$ percent of primes spilts completely in $K$(Chebotarev's density theorem)

・Since $K$ does not contain $\Bbb{Q}(i)$, $K\cap \Bbb{Q}(i)=\Bbb{Q}$.

・$p$ such that $p≡3\pmod4$ does not spilt in $\Bbb{Q}(i)/\Bbb{Q}$.

How can I combine these facts to prove the statement ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Formatting point:  use `\bmod` or `\pmod` in place of *mod*

Comment: delete "percent, write "split" instead of spilt, and use Bauer's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauerian_extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $K(i)$ is the compositum of $K$ and $\mathbb Q(i)$. Hence, a prime $p$ splits in $K(i)$ if and only if it splits in $K$ and in $\mathbb Q(i)$. It follows that
$$\{p: p\text{ splits in }K(i)\} = \{p\equiv 1\pmod 4 : p\text{ splits in }K\}.$$

Suppose that almost all of the primes that split in $K$ are $1\pmod 4$. Then the densities of the sets
$$\{p : p\text{ splits in }K(i)\},\ \{p\equiv 1\pmod 4 : p\text{ splits in }K\},\text{ and }\{p : p\text{ splits in }K\}$$
are equal, contradicting the Chebotarev density theorem.

Comment: Could you tell me why $p$ splits(ramify) in $KL$ is equivalent to $p$ splits(ramify) in $K$ and  $L$ ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78091/splitting-of-primes-in-the-compositum-of-fields. But be careful... replace splits completely with totally ramifies and the result is false.